# SolusVM Migration

Tags: vps, openvz, solusvm

I have an old server on which I am hosting about 30 OpenVZ VPS Servers. I have purchased a new server which is much more powerful and I plan to do a complete migration in the future. Currently I would like to know how to migrate VPS servers one by one, where the migrated VPS would keep all of the configuration, IP addresses and be completely independent from the server it was migrated from.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you have to use the **vzmigrate** command to transfer VPS's one at a time
https://documentation.solusvm.com/display/DOCS/Migrating+OpenVZ+Containers

Or you can migrate whole **/vz/private** directory and then all configs from **/etc/sysconfig/vz-scripts/** using something like this:

```
# cd /vz
# nice tar cpPf - private | ssh -e none -c blowfish IP_of_dest_server '(cd /vz; tar xpPf -)'
# scp /etc/sysconfig/vz-scripts/*.conf root@IP_of_dest_server:/etc/sysconfig/vz-scripts/
```